# Can I disable the Dock icon bouncing behavior of a particular OS X app?

Tags: macos, info.plist, dock

Is it possible to modify for example the `Info.plist` to prevent a certain app from making its Dock icon jump using `-[NSApplication requestUserAttention:]`? There is a system-wide setting `no-bouncing` which allows to disable the bouncing behavior completely, but that's not what I want.